# arch installed without bootloader - how to fix without using GRUB

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, boot-loader

Followed the installation guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide

1. At the point it directs to install a boot loader I saw on this page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_boot_process#Boot_loader that there are a number of options other than GRUB.
2. I see from this page in a posting by Johan Myreen that GRUB is not required, that a with a EFI  system the 'BIOS' loads the kernel.

I obviously missed a step because I boot to a blank screen with a blinking cursor.

- Can I rescue the installation?
- I see that the EFI partition is flagged as `msftdata` . Is that correct.
- How do I go about installing and configuring the systemd-boot ?

Comment: You can boot with some boot medium, mount your filesystems, chroot into your installation, and run whatever commands you need to run on arch to install a boot loader (or otherwise tweak EFI to boot your kernel)

Comment: ESP - efi system partition should have esp, boot flags. See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot